# Not recognizing global arrays

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, nullpointerexception, global-variables

Okay, I'm probably doing something dumb but I haven't been able to figure out what. I need to create a global array with an initial capacity, but it seems whenever I try, it throws some error. Right now I have:

```
public class Trains {
private static final int INITIAL = 30;
private static Integer[] train1, train2, train3, train4, train5, train6 = new Integer[INITIAL];
public Trains(){ //constructor
train2[0] = 4;
}
public static void move(){
System.out.println(train2[0]);
}
```

When I run this I get a null pointer exception when it tries to output train2[0] even though I initialized it. I've also tried this:

```
private static final int INITIAL = 30;
private static Integer[] train1, train2, train3, train4, train5, train6;
public Trains(){ //constructor
    train1, train2, train3, train4, train5, train6 = new Integer[INITIAL];
    train2[0] = 4;
}
```

But then it tells me that train1 through train6 cannot be resolved to a type.

I'm probably messing something up when trying to set the new Integer(INITIAL) because I've never used that before, but I haven't been able to find anything yet to help me figure out the problem.

Comment: Stop doing nothing but static variables. In your main, create an instance of Trains (Trains trains = new Trains()) and call methods on the trains instance. Piling everything in main or as static is a horribly bad pattern.

Comment: You also need to provide the exact error and what line it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You have only initialized `Integer[] train6 = new Integer[INITIAL];`

The others are still set to null. Before setting the value at train2[0], check if train2 is null.

```
if(train2 == null) 
    train2 = new Integer[INITIAL];

train2[0] = 4;
```

Does that make it clear?

P.S. In the future, be more specific about where exactly your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
private static Integer[] train1, train2, train3, train4, 
                         train5, train6 = new Integer[INITIAL];
```

with

```
private static Integer[] train1 = new Integer[INITIAL];
private static Integer[] train2 = new Integer[INITIAL];
private static Integer[] train3 = new Integer[INITIAL];
// etcetera
```

Yes it is verbose, but that's what you get if your code is "defactored" to use multiple array variables like that.

I think you should consider using an `Integer[][]` whose first dimension is `6`.  That is likely to simplify other things as well ... if you do the refactoring the right way.

---

For the record, the reason that why your first attempt failed is that

```
private static Integer[] train1, train2, train3, train4, 
                         train5, train6 = new Integer[INITIAL];
```

is equivalent to

```
private static Integer[] train1;
private static Integer[] train2;
// etcetera.
private static Integer[] train6 = new Integer[INITIAL];
```

This is clear if you look at that Java syntax rules: e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2